# The best way to store variable across different widgets

Tags: wp-query, post-duplication

The front page of my site building with set of widgets.
Each widget shows the rows with posts for some criteria.

I want to exclude duplicate posts across different widgets.
The simplest way comes to mind is to use global variable.

For example:

```
global $exclude;

$query = new WP_Query([
  'posts_per_page' => publish, 
  'post__not_in' => $exclude
]);

$exclude = wp_list_pluck( $query->posts, 'ID' );
```

I want to find better way to do this job. I've thought about `wp_get_cache`, but it seems that it is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no one answers my question so I will show my way to solve this problem.

I use [public query vars](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars) with `get_query_var` and `set_query_var` functions to set `widget__exclude` variable across all queries.

Still not sure that it is the best way for this case but hope it helps somebody.